# ServiceSIBusMessageBean must implement interface javax.jms.MessageListener

Tags: java, queue, websphere

We have project on WebSphere:

```
IBM WebSphere Integration Developer  
Version: 6.2.0.3  
Build id: 6.2.0.3-IFix-20100827_1244
```

With default WebSphere Process Server shipped with.
I created follow queues configuration:

```
statisticASReqestJNDI <-> statisticRequestQJNDI  <-> statisticRequestSIBQJNDI   
statisticASResponseJNDI <-> statisticResponseQJNDI <-> statisticResponseSIBQJNDI
statisticCFJNDI <-> Default Bus
```

I have follow diagram as in picture attached:

[image: JMS Connector Diagram]

When I try to deploy the NeoflexStatistics module, I have follow error in SystemOut:

```
[11/22/16 10:34:12:947 MSK] 0000005f ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\WID62\pf\wps\logs\ffdc\server1_0000005f_16.11.22_10.34.12_0.txt
[11/22/16 10:34:12:958 MSK] 0000005f ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\WID62\pf\wps\logs\ffdc\server1_0000005f_16.11.22_10.34.12_0.txt
```

And follow dump in referenced file:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [11/22/16 10:24:55:598 MSK] , key = javax.management.MBeanException com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service 212
Exception = javax.management.MBeanException
Source = com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service
probeid = 212
Stack Dump = javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1119)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:973)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MetaDataImpl.invoke(MetaDataImpl.java:238)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:833)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1139)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:361)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:215)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:742)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: Bean class could not be found or loaded; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: MDB com.ibm.wsspi.sca.async.bean.impl.ServiceSIBusMessageBean must implement interface javax.jms.MessageListener
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.install(EJBContainerImpl.java:3064)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3730)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1250)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1167)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:834)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1437)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4192)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4290)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:245)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:271)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: Bean class could not be found or loaded; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: MDB com.ibm.wsspi.sca.async.bean.impl.ServiceSIBusMessageBean must implement interface javax.jms.MessageListener
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.processBean(EJBContainerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.install(EJBContainerImpl.java:2868)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: Bean class could not be found or loaded; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: MDB com.ibm.wsspi.sca.async.bean.impl.ServiceSIBusMessageBean must implement interface javax.jms.MessageListener
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanMetaData.completeInitialization(BeanMetaData.java:2335)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createBeanMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:2009)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.processBean(EJBContainerImpl.java:1818)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerException: MDB com.ibm.wsspi.sca.async.bean.impl.ServiceSIBusMessageBean must implement interface javax.jms.MessageListener
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanMetaData.completeInitialization(BeanMetaData.java:1799)
    ... 42 more

Dump of callerThis = 
Object type = com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector
com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector@4b384b38

==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ws.management.dm.ConnectorDM  = Tue Nov 22 10:24:55 MSK 2016
Dump of callerThis = 
Object type = com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector
  bundleName = com.ibm.ws.management.resources.connector
  tc = 
    defaultMessageFile = com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
    EXTENSION_NAME_DPID = DiagnosticProvider
    ivDumpEnabled = false
    ivResourceBundleName = com.ibm.ws.management.resources.connector
    ivLogger = null
    ivDiagnosticProviderID = null
    anyTracingEnabled = false
    ivLevel = 10
    ivName = com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector
    ivDebugEnabled = false
    ivEventEnabled = false
    ivEntryEnabled = false
    ivDetailEnabled = false
    ivConfigEnabled = false
    ivInfoEnabled = true
    ivServiceEnabled = true
    ivWarningEnabled = true
    ivErrorEnabled = true
    ivFatalEnabled = true
  nls = 
    tc = com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@75227522
    nullKey = null Key
    svNullBundleName = Resource Bundle name is null, key = {0}
    svBundleNotLoaded = Unable to load ResourceBundle {0}
    svNullKeyMessage = Null key passed while using ResourceBundle {0}
    svMalformedMessage = No message text associated with key {0} in bundle {1}
    sbConvertMessageIds = false
    svMessageIdPropertyName = com.ibm.websphere.logging.messageId.version
    svResolver = com.ibm.ejs.ras.BundleResolverImpl@1f801f80
    ivBundleName = com.ibm.ws.management.resources.connector
    class$com$ibm$ejs$ras$TraceNLS = java.lang.Class@19d919d9
  targetObject = 
    tc = com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@48704870
    _adminInstance = com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl@4cb04cb0
    class$com$ibm$ws$management$connector$AdminServiceDelegator = java.lang.Class@21a021a0
  smr = 
    tc = com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@d320d32
    defaultSerializer = com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.GenericSerializer@530c530c
    singleton = this.smr
    class$com$ibm$ws$management$connector$soap$AdminServiceSMR = java.lang.Class@25d525d5
    class$java$lang$Boolean = java.lang.Class@6b6a6b6a
    class$java$lang$Character = java.lang.Class@3eae3eae
    class$java$lang$Number = java.lang.Class@6cbe6cbe
    sReg = java.util.Hashtable@5adc5adc
    dsReg = java.util.Hashtable@5af65af6
    xml2JavaReg = java.util.Hashtable@5b105b10
    java2XMLReg = java.util.Hashtable@5b2a5b2a
    defaultEncodingStyle = null
  securityEnabled = true
  class$com$ibm$ws$management$connector$soap$SOAPConnector = 
    serialVersionUID = 3206093459760846163
    AllPermissionsPD = java.security.ProtectionDomain@4f544f54
    SYNTHETIC = 4096
    ANNOTATION = 8192
    ENUM = 16384
    j9Version = 453640753
    j9Config = 8314596479310233600
    EmptyParameters = {}
    copyMethod = java.lang.reflect.Method@5be05be0
    copyField = java.lang.reflect.Method@5c105c10
    copyConstructor = java.lang.reflect.Method@5c685c68
    methodParameterTypesField = java.lang.reflect.Field@5b705b70
    constructorParameterTypesField = java.lang.reflect.Field@5c3c5c3c
    NoArgs = {}
    PublicKey = java.lang.Class$CacheKey@540054
    DeclaredKey = java.lang.Class$CacheKey@5c005c
    queue = java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue@91e091e

+Data for directive [defaultconnector] obtained. = 
==> Dump complete for com.ibm.ws.management.dm.ConnectorDM  = Tue Nov 22 10:24:55 MSK 2016
```

I have no idea what I can do...

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: OK, can you move it there?

Comment: Flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it (be specific about where you want it moved to).